# MySql Select Satement doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very simple select statement:

```
$sqllinks = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notif WHERE mem_id = '$logOptions_id' AND read = '0' ORDER BY date") or die (mysql_error()); // query the member
$numofnotif = mysql_num_rows($sqllinks);
```

however i constantly get the error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'read = '0' ORDER BY date' at line 1

I have tried everything that I can think of to try to get this to work but somehow it doesn't.

Thank you.

Comment: Data type of 'read' column? If it is int based drop the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`READ` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  Quote it in backticks:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     notif
WHERE    mem_id = '$logOptions_id' AND `read` = '0'
ORDER BY date
```